# Teamviewer VPN blocked by Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-firewall, teamviewer

I am using Teamviewer 9 and would like to use the VPN option. I installed it all and it works perfectly only if I turn off the Windows firewall on my VPN target. Teamviewer.exe ia already allowed through. Does anyone know what rules I need to setup to let the VPN tunnel through? Both machines are Windows 8.1.

~Gary

Comment: Have you looked at what port and protocol is set in your TeamViewer configuration?

Comment: Nope. I just looked in it and I do not see where to view those settings. I do see the box for Use UDP is checked.

Comment: Team viewer uses port 80, 443, and 5938. You just to need to punch a hole for port 5938 (TCP and UDP). If that doesn't work I would just fire up wireshark and see what port it's using when the firewalls off.

Comment: l0sts0ck, Wireshark lists 4 different ports as UDP so I opened them all. Still will not work.

Comment: Is the TeamViewer_Service also allowed?

Comment: Nathan C, yes it is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, and it could also be easily bypassed by turning off firewall - however I said **NO** to that solution (for security reasons).....

**I solved this by setting sharing options *(no Firewall settings were needed)*:**

1. Go to *Control Panel* => *Network and Sharing Center*
2. On the left, click on *Change advanced sharing settings*
3. Expand the network profile your TeamViewer VPNetowrk is in (probably Public profile)
4. **SOLVING POINT:** In sub-section *File and printer sharing* choose *Turn **on** file and printer sharing*
5. (optional but **security**) As you may be on more public networks, not just TeamViewer VPN:
   For **security** reasons you should also set this in that network profile:

   - *Network discovery* => *Turn **off** network discovery*
   - *Public folder sharing* => *Turn **off** Public folder sharing (...)*
   - *Password protected sharing* => *Turn **on** password protected sharing*
   - If you can, choose the best encryption you can (probably 128bit)

Answer (score 2):

Allowing TCP port 445 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Windows Firewall" then  "advanced setting"
then go to "Windows Firewall Properties"
There are 3 tabs: Domain Profile, Private Profile, Public Profile
Go to each tab
Choose "Allow" under "Inbound Connections"
and reboot the computer
It will resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are not having ping response but the VPN is working.
Check it.
The VPN connection IS established, despite you are not having an answer to your ping because there's a
default "Global Rule" in Comodo Firewall to block incoming ECHO REQUESTS.

See "Global Rules", is the last one on the list: "Block ICMPv4 in From MAC Any To MAC Any Where ICMP Message is ECHO REQUEST"
Delete that rule and you will have your pings answered.

Comment: That is nice for Comodo Firewall, however this question relates to **Windows Firewall**.